# Access JavaScript array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a HTML code like this:

```
 <body>
  <div id="vis">
   <div id="loading-container"><img src="img/loading.gif" id="loading" /><img src="img/loaded.gif" id="loaded" /></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Within the `vis` div, more elements are added dynamically and they all have the same tag type:

```
<svg class="example" width="800" height="400"></svg>
```

I want to get all the `svg` elements, which I've done like this:

```
var visDiv = document.getElementById("vis");
var svgDiv = visDiv.getElementsByTagName("svg");
```

I am trying iterate through `svgDiv`, however it outputs a length of 0 even though there are multiple elements there. When I console.log `svgDiv`I get:

```
SVG: [item: function, namedItem: function]
      0: svg
      1: svg
      length: 2
      __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

This seems like a obvious question but how can I access the "0" & "1" objects?

`svgDiv["item"][0]` results in `undefined`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use jquery and the "on" function that checks the whole doom again for elements

Comment: svgDiv[0], svgDiv[1], etc... (just like a normal array expando)

Comment: @dandavis: I already tried that, I get `undefined` as well

Comment: maybe it needs `getElementsByTagNameNS`, but i swear it looks fine...

Comment: SVG[0][item] shows what? Can you open a jsfiddle?

Comment: @dandavis: `getElementsByTagNameN` didn't yield different results

Comment: who in the world uses .item to access a collection? is that a thing? probably the same folks who prefer `localStorage.getItem("key")` instead of `localStorage.key`...

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: `svgDiv[0][item]` results in " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined". Unfortunately opening a jsFiddle won't help because it's an application running on my local server

Comment: Try this: _setTimeout(function(){ console.log(svgDiv[0][item]) }, 2000);_ ... if it works, then your problem is you need load the content before searching for it.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: You guys were right, I didn't think to use a timeout. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
svgDiv[0]
```

since

```
visDiv.getElementsByTagName("svg");
```

returns an array of all elements with the tag "svg" and you want to access it's first (or generally speaking n-th) element.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9uyqfut/)

Comment: did you make sure that they are already added to your content? I hard-coded them into your div and everything works fine. Did you try to access them before they were completely added to your site? (I added a jsfiddle to my answer)

Comment: You were right, I added a timeout before searching the array and now it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

svgDiv is returning as an [HTML collection.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) -- you should be able to get these elements by using

```
svgDiv.item(0)
svgDiv.item(1)
```

Comment: I get `null` for both

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to access the elements before they have been added to the div? 

I've got a basic jsFiddle that seems to be working, maybe you can mod it to match your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/qd6gw6o2/

Comment: You were right, I added a timeout before searching the array and now it works. Thanks for your help!